# Socket Programming C, receiving messages is carrying over from previous messages

Tags: c, sockets, pointers, char

Hi I'm trying to create a simple username/password read and write between my Server and my Client application. Currently my Client side is working perfectly. The issue I am having is inside my Server side. When I enter a username on the Client side it is captured by my Server correctly. See the following code:

```
void authenticate_process(int cli_sockfd){

    /* Authentication Process */
    write(cli_sockfd, "USN", 3);
    char *username;
    username = recv_msg(cli_sockfd);
    printf("[DEBUG] Client username is %s.\n", username);

    write(cli_sockfd, "PSW", 3);
    char *password;
    password = recv_msg(cli_sockfd);
    printf("[DEBUG] Client Password is %s.\n", password);

}
```

The problem is for example the user types "Johnabscaras" as the username then the code places the last "ras" into what is the password variable. My recv_msg function looks like the following:

```
/* Reads a message from the server socket. */
char *recv_msg(int sockfd)
{
    int length;
    char *msg;
    msg = (char*) malloc (9);

    /* All messages are 9 bytes. */
    int n = read(sockfd, msg, 9);
    return msg;

}
```

As the username and password is never larger than 9 bytes it is set for this. But I have found out that upon first entering the username if you type more that 9 characters the extra characters will be amended to the password variable. If you type less than 9 characters the code skips over and the password variable is immediately set to " " for some reason. Can someone please explain and show me how to fix this?

Comment: Makes sense to me, more than 9 bytes were sent, but you only read 9, the remaining bytes will be returned in the next read.  Maybe try fflush(sockfd) between reading the name and password.

Comment: What you're seeing is the expected behavior -- keep in mind that TCP implements a stream-of-bytes, not a stream-of-messages; that is to say, TCP does not preserve message boundaries, so you will always receive the bytes that were sent, in the order they were sent, but not necessarily in the same groupings.    For your case, the easy fix would be to modify the sending program to truncate the string before sending it, so that it is never longer than 9 bytes.

Comment: Thisisusernamethisispasswordpraytellmehowthepoorcomputercouldpossiblyknowwhichiswhich?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using a stream socket (`SOCK_STREAM`, i.e. TCP). A stream socket is basically (from the point of view of your program) just a bidirectional pipe.

There is no concept of "messages" beyond what your application imposes. The socket just sends and receives a single, long stream of bytes. `write(fd, "foo", 3); write(fd, "bar", 3);` has the same effect as `write(fd, "foobar", 6);`. It's sending the same bytes in the same order.

If you want your streams to transfer multiple separate messages, you have to encode those message boundaries somehow.

- For example, you could decide that every message is exactly 100 bytes long and then always send/receive exactly 100 bytes.
- Or you could mark the end of a message with an explicit terminator (such as `'\0'`). The receiving code would then have to loop until it sees a `'\0'`.
- Or you could send a length field as the first part of each message; that way the receiving code knows in advance how many bytes it needs to allocate and read.

This comment in your code indicates that you chose option 1:

```
/* All messages are 9 bytes. */
```

But apparently the sending code has a bug because it tries to transmit a message of more than 9 bytes, which of course is then interpreted as multiple messages. If the client sends 12 bytes, then that's a message of 9 bytes followed by another (incomplete) message of 3 bytes. "*Currently my Client side is working perfectly*"? No, it isn't; at least not if your receiving code is correct.

Another issue is

```
printf("[DEBUG] Client username is %s.\n", username);
```

`%s` expects a C string, i.e. a nul-terminated sequence of characters. `username` has no NUL terminator (unless the client decided to explicitly send a `'\0'` byte as part of the message). In fact, users of `recv_msg` have no way of telling how much data was received. If it's always exactly 9 bytes,

```
printf("%.9s", username);
```

would work, but `recv_msg` doesn't make sure that this is the case:

```
int n = read(sockfd, msg, 9);
```

It simply ignores `n`, so it's possible for all or parts of `msg` to be uninitialized and the calling code cannot tell.